# Best way to pass Powershell Object[] to C# Method

Tags: c#, powershell, unit-testing, mstest

I have a results object which is collection of PowerShell Object[] which is pulled from an external API.

[image: PowerShell Object[21] that is returned from an external API]

At the moment I test for the existence of the property TimeStampUtc by using the following following PowerShell code:

```
$property = $dataSet | Get-Member -Name TimeStampUtc
if($null -ne $property -and $property.Definition -match 'datetime')
{
    # Process code here
}
```

We are trying to migrate some of our PowerShell logic into C# so it's more portable but I am not sure what type to pass the results object into a C#.

```
public string CreateLineChart(object[] dataSet)
{
    if (dataSet.GetType().GetProperty("TimeStampUtc") != null)
    {
        // Process code here
    }
```

Would anyone have any idea on the best type to pass to the C# method and still be able to test for the properties and extract values?

Is it also possible to create a PowerShell Object[] in C# so I can test passing the same values from a C# unit test? If I try passing a C# object reflection always treats it as the type I created it with for example an ExpandoObject.

Comment: Read up on the `dynamic` type.  It's basically the same as an `object`, except that, like Powershell, the object is queried for a property or method at runtime and if it exists, it calls it.  Scripting languages and `dynamic` fit together very well

Answer (score 0):

After looking deeper with some of our team we realized in our upstream code we were created a PSObject to store the data. We will change this to use a Dictionary<DateTime, double> and it will simplify out implementation.